# how to deal with different length of xts variable in r?

Tags: r

I am working on stock markets of two different nations, i.e China and the US. I used "quantmod" library in r, to import daily historical prices from yahoo finance. My sample data belongs form 01 JAN 2010 to 31 March 2015, but due to the different culture of these nations they have holidays on different dates and stock markets are closed on those days. Hence, i have different no. of rows of data and I can not apply the garch model on these values. For example, stock market of China has 1267 rows (one column) and the US market has 1303 rows (one column).

**now my question is, how can I make a data frame with similar dates and delete/ skip the values with different dates?**

my codes and error in r are given below,

```
library("rugarch")
library("rmgarch")
library("quantmod")
startdate<-as.Date("2010-01-01")
enddate<-as.Date("2015-03-31")
getSymbols("^SSEC", from=startdate, to=enddate)
getSymbols("^GSPC", from=startdate, to=enddate)
rsse<-dailyReturn(SSEC$SSEC.Close) # *calculate returns*
rgspc<-dailyReturn(GSPC$GSPC.Close)# *calculate returns*
returns<-data.frame(rsse, rgspc) # *making data frame with both market returns*
**Error**
Error in data.frame(rsse, rgspc) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1267, 1303
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do an inner join on two dataframes. Each dataframe needs to have a date and the price for that day. I don't know the structure of your dataframes but something like:

```
dplyr::inner_join(SSEC, GSPC, by='my.date.variable')
```

or if the two dataframes have different names for their date variables, for example `SSEC_date` and `GSPC_date`:

```
dplyr::inner_join(SSEC, GSPC, by=c('SSEC_date' = 'GSPC_date'))
```